# Ruby cairo gem failing to install on Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: ruby, macos, cairo

I am completely stuck on this.  Working ruby on rails app that had dependency on cairo.  After upgrading from Mac OS X Mavericks to Yosemite and doing a bundle install it fails to install cairo gem.  I have tried playing around with the versions of gcc between 4.2 (apple's bundled patched version) vs 4.8 and 4.9 with no luck.  Any ideas are welcome...

sudo gem install cairo
Password:

```
Fetching: pkg-config-1.1.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed pkg-config-1.1.5
Fetching: cairo-1.12.9.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cairo:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/Ben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p550/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20141110-82223-1dv66fm.rb extconf.rb
checking for GCC... yes
checking for Win32 OS... no
checking for cairo version (>= 1.2.0)... yes
checking for Mac OS X... yes
checking for HAVE_RUBY_ST_H in ruby.h... yes
checking for HAVE_RUBY_IO_H in ruby.h... yes
checking for rb_errinfo() in ruby.h... yes
checking for enum ruby_value_type in ruby.h... yes
creating Makefile

make  clean

make
compiling rb_cairo.c
couldn't understand kern.osversion `14.0.0'
rb_cairo.c: In function ‘rb_cairo_satisfied_version’:
rb_cairo.c:31: warning: unused parameter ‘self’
compiling rb_cairo_constants.c
couldn't understand kern.osversion `14.0.0'
rb_cairo_constants.c: In function ‘rb_cairo_operator_from_ruby_object’:
rb_cairo_constants.c:152: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false
rb_cairo_constants.c: In function ‘rb_cairo_antialias_from_ruby_object’:
rb_cairo_constants.c:153: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false
rb_cairo_constants.c: In function ‘rb_cairo_fill_rule_from_ruby_object’:
rb_cairo_constants.c:154: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false
rb_cairo_constants.c: In function ‘rb_cairo_line_cap_from_ruby_object’:
rb_cairo_constants.c:155: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false
rb_cairo_constants.c: In function ‘rb_cairo_line_join_from_ruby_object’:
rb_cairo_constants.c:156: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false
rb_cairo_constants.c: In function ‘rb_cairo_font_slant_from_ruby_object’:
rb_cairo_constants.c:157: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false
rb_cairo_constants.c: In function ‘rb_cairo_font_weight_from_ruby_object’:
rb_cairo_constants.c:158: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false
rb_cairo_constants.c: In function ‘rb_cairo_subpixel_order_from_ruby_object’:
rb_cairo_constants.c:159: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false
rb_cairo_constants.c: In function ‘rb_cairo_hint_style_from_ruby_object’:
rb_cairo_constants.c:160: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false
rb_cairo_constants.c: In function ‘rb_cairo_hint_metrics_from_ruby_object’:
rb_cairo_constants.c:161: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false
rb_cairo_constants.c: In function ‘rb_cairo_path_data_type_from_ruby_object’:
rb_cairo_constants.c:162: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false
rb_cairo_constants.c: In function ‘rb_cairo_extend_from_ruby_object’:
rb_cairo_constants.c:165: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false
rb_cairo_constants.c: In function ‘rb_cairo_filter_from_ruby_object’:
rb_cairo_constants.c:166: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false
rb_cairo_constants.c: In function ‘rb_cairo_svg_version_from_ruby_object’:
rb_cairo_constants.c:168: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false
rb_cairo_constants.c: In function ‘rb_cairo_ps_level_from_ruby_object’:
rb_cairo_constants.c:173: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false
rb_cairo_constants.c: In function ‘rb_cairo_pdf_version_from_ruby_object’:
rb_cairo_constants.c:180: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false
rb_cairo_constants.c: In function ‘rb_cairo_text_cluster_flags_from_ruby_object’:
rb_cairo_constants.c:186: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false
rb_cairo_constants.c: In function ‘rb_cairo_script_mode_from_ruby_object’:
rb_cairo_constants.c:190: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false
rb_cairo_constants.c: In function ‘rb_cairo_region_overlap_from_ruby_object’:
rb_cairo_constants.c:194: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false
rb_cairo_constants.c: In function ‘cr_svg_get_versions’:
rb_cairo_constants.c:208: warning: unused parameter ‘self’
rb_cairo_constants.c: In function ‘cr_svg_version_to_string’:
rb_cairo_constants.c:227: warning: unused parameter ‘self’
rb_cairo_constants.c: In function ‘cr_format_stride_for_width’:
rb_cairo_constants.c:246: warning: unused parameter ‘self’
rb_cairo_constants.c: In function ‘cr_ps_get_levels’:
rb_cairo_constants.c:256: warning: unused parameter ‘self’
rb_cairo_constants.c: In function ‘cr_ps_level_to_string’:
rb_cairo_constants.c:274: warning: unused parameter ‘self’
rb_cairo_constants.c: In function ‘cr_pdf_get_versions’:
rb_cairo_constants.c:293: warning: unused parameter ‘self’
rb_cairo_constants.c: In function ‘cr_pdf_version_to_string’:
rb_cairo_constants.c:311: warning: unused parameter ‘self’
compiling rb_cairo_context.c
couldn't understand kern.osversion `14.0.0'
rb_cairo_context.c: In function ‘cr_destroy_all_guarded_contexts_at_end_iter’:
rb_cairo_context.c:1496: warning: unused parameter ‘value’
rb_cairo_context.c:1496: warning: unused parameter ‘data’
rb_cairo_context.c: In function ‘cr_destroy_all_guarded_contexts_at_end’:
rb_cairo_context.c:1503: warning: unused parameter ‘data’
compiling rb_cairo_device.c
couldn't understand kern.osversion `14.0.0'
rb_cairo_device.c: In function ‘cr_device_script_supported_p’:
rb_cairo_device.c:100: warning: unused parameter ‘klass’
rb_cairo_device.c: In function ‘cr_device_xml_supported_p’:
rb_cairo_device.c:110: warning: unused parameter ‘klass’
rb_cairo_device.c: In function ‘cr_device_initialize’:
rb_cairo_device.c:192: warning: unused parameter ‘argc’
rb_cairo_device.c:192: warning: unused parameter ‘argv’
rb_cairo_device.c: In function ‘cr_finish_all_guarded_devices_at_end_iter’:
rb_cairo_device.c:262: warning: unused parameter ‘value’
rb_cairo_device.c:262: warning: unused parameter ‘data’
rb_cairo_device.c: In function ‘cr_finish_all_guarded_devices_at_end’:
rb_cairo_device.c:269: warning: unused parameter ‘data’
compiling rb_cairo_exception.c
couldn't understand kern.osversion `14.0.0'
rb_cairo_exception.c: In function ‘rb_cairo_check_status’:
rb_cairo_exception.c:70: warning: enumeration value ‘CAIRO_STATUS_JBIG2_GLOBAL_MISSING’ not handled in switch
compiling rb_cairo_font_extents.c
couldn't understand kern.osversion `14.0.0'
compiling rb_cairo_font_face.c
couldn't understand kern.osversion `14.0.0'
compiling rb_cairo_font_options.c
couldn't understand kern.osversion `14.0.0'
compiling rb_cairo_glyph.c
couldn't understand kern.osversion `14.0.0'
compiling rb_cairo_io.c
couldn't understand kern.osversion `14.0.0'
compiling rb_cairo_matrix.c
couldn't understand kern.osversion `14.0.0'
rb_cairo_matrix.c: In function ‘cr_matrix_init_identity’:
rb_cairo_matrix.c:86: warning: unused parameter ‘self’
rb_cairo_matrix.c: In function ‘cr_matrix_init_translate’:
rb_cairo_matrix.c:94: warning: unused parameter ‘self’
rb_cairo_matrix.c: In function ‘cr_matrix_init_scale’:
rb_cairo_matrix.c:102: warning: unused parameter ‘self’
rb_cairo_matrix.c: In function ‘cr_matrix_init_rotate’:
rb_cairo_matrix.c:110: warning: unused parameter ‘self’
compiling rb_cairo_path.c
couldn't understand kern.osversion `14.0.0'
rb_cairo_path.c: In function ‘cr_path_move_to_initialize’:
rb_cairo_path.c:139: warning: unused parameter ‘self’
rb_cairo_path.c: In function ‘cr_path_line_to_initialize’:
rb_cairo_path.c:158: warning: unused parameter ‘self’
rb_cairo_path.c: In function ‘cr_path_curve_to_initialize’:
rb_cairo_path.c:177: warning: unused parameter ‘self’
rb_cairo_path.c: In function ‘cr_path_close_path_initialize’:
rb_cairo_path.c:213: warning: unused parameter ‘self’
compiling rb_cairo_pattern.c
couldn't understand kern.osversion `14.0.0'
rb_cairo_pattern.c: In function ‘cr_pattern_solid_supported_p’:
rb_cairo_pattern.c:87: warning: unused parameter ‘klass’
rb_cairo_pattern.c: In function ‘cr_pattern_surface_supported_p’:
rb_cairo_pattern.c:93: warning: unused parameter ‘klass’
rb_cairo_pattern.c: In function ‘cr_pattern_gradient_supported_p’:
rb_cairo_pattern.c:99: warning: unused parameter ‘klass’
rb_cairo_pattern.c: In function ‘cr_pattern_linear_supported_p’:
rb_cairo_pattern.c:105: warning: unused parameter ‘klass’
rb_cairo_pattern.c: In function ‘cr_pattern_radial_supported_p’:
rb_cairo_pattern.c:111: warning: unused parameter ‘klass’
rb_cairo_pattern.c: In function ‘cr_pattern_mesh_supported_p’:
rb_cairo_pattern.c:117: warning: unused parameter ‘klass’
rb_cairo_pattern.c: In function ‘cr_pattern_raster_source_supported_p’:
rb_cairo_pattern.c:127: warning: unused parameter ‘klass’
rb_cairo_pattern.c: In function ‘cr_pattern_initialize’:
rb_cairo_pattern.c:180: warning: unused parameter ‘argc’
rb_cairo_pattern.c:180: warning: unused parameter ‘argv’
rb_cairo_pattern.c: In function ‘cr_mesh_pattern_set_control_point’:
rb_cairo_pattern.c:598: warning: comparison of unsigned expression >= 0 is always true
rb_cairo_pattern.c: In function ‘cr_mesh_pattern_set_corner_color_generic’:
rb_cairo_pattern.c:628: warning: comparison of unsigned expression >= 0 is always true
rb_cairo_pattern.c: In function ‘cr_mesh_pattern_get_corner_color’:
rb_cairo_pattern.c:692: warning: comparison of unsigned expression >= 0 is always true
rb_cairo_pattern.c: In function ‘cr_mesh_pattern_get_control_point’:
rb_cairo_pattern.c:726: warning: comparison of unsigned expression >= 0 is always true
rb_cairo_pattern.c: In function ‘cr_raster_source_acquire_callback’:
rb_cairo_pattern.c:748: warning: unused parameter ‘pattern’
rb_cairo_pattern.c: In function ‘cr_raster_source_release_callback’:
rb_cairo_pattern.c:781: warning: unused parameter ‘pattern’
rb_cairo_pattern.c: In function ‘cr_raster_source_snapshot_callback’:
rb_cairo_pattern.c:830: warning: unused parameter ‘pattern’
rb_cairo_pattern.c: In function ‘cr_raster_source_copy_callback’:
rb_cairo_pattern.c:854: warning: unused parameter ‘pattern’
rb_cairo_pattern.c:856: warning: unused parameter ‘other’
rb_cairo_pattern.c: In function ‘cr_raster_source_finish_callback’:
rb_cairo_pattern.c:879: warning: unused parameter ‘pattern’
compiling rb_cairo_private.c
couldn't understand kern.osversion `14.0.0'
compiling rb_cairo_rectangle.c
couldn't understand kern.osversion `14.0.0'
compiling rb_cairo_region.c
couldn't understand kern.osversion `14.0.0'
compiling rb_cairo_scaled_font.c
couldn't understand kern.osversion `14.0.0'
compiling rb_cairo_surface.c
couldn't understand kern.osversion `14.0.0'
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:55,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Headers/ApplicationServices.h:23,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/cairo/1.14.0/include/cairo/cairo-quartz.h:43,
                 from rb_cairo_surface.c:54:
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/FSEvents.framework/Headers/FSEvents.h:262: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘}’ before ‘__attribute__’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/FSEvents.framework/Headers/FSEvents.h:414: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘}’ before ‘__attribute__’
rb_cairo_surface.c: In function ‘cr_surface_image_supported_p’:
rb_cairo_surface.c:230: warning: unused parameter ‘klass’
rb_cairo_surface.c: In function ‘cr_surface_pdf_supported_p’:
rb_cairo_surface.c:236: warning: unused parameter ‘klass’
rb_cairo_surface.c: In function ‘cr_surface_ps_supported_p’:
rb_cairo_surface.c:246: warning: unused parameter ‘klass’
rb_cairo_surface.c: In function ‘cr_surface_quartz_supported_p’:
rb_cairo_surface.c:256: warning: unused parameter ‘klass’
rb_cairo_surface.c: In function ‘cr_surface_win32_supported_p’:
rb_cairo_surface.c:266: warning: unused parameter ‘klass’
rb_cairo_surface.c: In function ‘cr_surface_svg_supported_p’:
rb_cairo_surface.c:276: warning: unused parameter ‘klass’
rb_cairo_surface.c: In function ‘cr_surface_win32_printing_supported_p’:
rb_cairo_surface.c:286: warning: unused parameter ‘klass’
rb_cairo_surface.c: In function ‘cr_surface_quartz_image_supported_p’:
rb_cairo_surface.c:296: warning: unused parameter ‘klass’
rb_cairo_surface.c: In function ‘cr_surface_script_supported_p’:
rb_cairo_surface.c:306: warning: unused parameter ‘klass’
rb_cairo_surface.c: In function ‘cr_surface_recording_supported_p’:
rb_cairo_surface.c:316: warning: unused parameter ‘klass’
rb_cairo_surface.c: In function ‘cr_surface_gl_supported_p’:
rb_cairo_surface.c:326: warning: unused parameter ‘klass’
rb_cairo_surface.c: In function ‘cr_surface_tee_supported_p’:
rb_cairo_surface.c:342: warning: unused parameter ‘klass’
rb_cairo_surface.c: In function ‘cr_surface_xml_supported_p’:
rb_cairo_surface.c:352: warning: unused parameter ‘klass’
rb_cairo_surface.c: In function ‘cr_surface_initialize’:
rb_cairo_surface.c:432: warning: unused parameter ‘argc’
rb_cairo_surface.c:432: warning: unused parameter ‘argv’
rb_cairo_surface.c: In function ‘cr_image_surface_create’:
rb_cairo_surface.c:923: warning: unused parameter ‘self’
rb_cairo_surface.c: In function ‘cr_image_surface_create_for_data’:
rb_cairo_surface.c:933: warning: unused parameter ‘self’
rb_cairo_surface.c: In function ‘cr_quartz_surface_initialize’:
rb_cairo_surface.c:1264: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
rb_cairo_surface.c: In function ‘cr_quartz_image_surface_initialize’:
rb_cairo_surface.c:1476: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘cairo_quartz_image_surface_create’
rb_cairo_surface.c:1476: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
rb_cairo_surface.c: In function ‘cr_quartz_image_surface_get_image’:
rb_cairo_surface.c:1489: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘cairo_quartz_image_surface_get_image’
rb_cairo_surface.c:1489: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
rb_cairo_surface.c: In function ‘cr_finish_all_guarded_surfaces_at_end_iter’:
rb_cairo_surface.c:1904: warning: unused parameter ‘value’
rb_cairo_surface.c:1904: warning: unused parameter ‘data’
rb_cairo_surface.c: In function ‘cr_finish_all_guarded_surfaces_at_end’:
rb_cairo_surface.c:1911: warning: unused parameter ‘data’
make: *** [rb_cairo_surface.o] Error 1
```

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Ben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p550/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cairo-1.12.9 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Ben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p550/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/1.9.1/cairo-1.12.9/gem_make.out

Comment: Thread about it here  https://github.com/luite/hfsevents/issues/9#issuecomment-62440670

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this issue by installing macports

https://www.macports.org/install.php

Then installing cairo directly
http://cairographics.org/download/

sudo port install cairo

Then gem install cairo worked.

Comment: This didn't work for me, just installing cairo with macport.  I also have a different compile issue now on ruby 2.1 and rails 3.2..

Comment: compiling rb_cairo_surface.c
In file included from /usr/include/dispatch/dispatch.h:51:0,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFStream.h:15,